# Simple Append Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have run into to a issue in C#.
I am trying to fill in a ImageUrl in a asp object, and it works fine as shown below.

**X = Is the asp:Image tag i target by ID**

**Y = The Value from my Sql Database, in this case its "products_img_large" the image name.**

`X.ImageUrl = reader["Y"].ToString();`

All of the above work, but what i really want is to, add a path infront of the result of "Y".

Like this:

```
X.ImageUrl = reader["img/"+"Y"].ToString();
```

But i can't make it work, and i lack the correct words to google it with relevant results.

Can anyone help or maby point out the error, i be quite happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite as

```
X.ImageUrl = "img/" + reader["Y"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to point out my simple error. When i tryed it the way you show it here the first time, I made the mistake of not using the "".

Answer (score 2):

In `reader["Y"].ToString()` "Y" describes the column name you want to access from your result. If you change the index  `["img/"+"Y"] the column to be looked up becomes "img/Y" and does probably not exist.

The search phrases you are probably looking for are combining strings, concatenate strings or interpolate strings.

You can just combine them using the + operator as BornToCode already showed:

```
X.ImageUrl = "img/" + reader["Y"].ToString();
```

You can use [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting):

```
X.ImageUrl = string.Format("img/{0}", reader["Y"]);
```

In C# 6 you can [interpolate strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx):

```
X.ImageUrl = $"img/{reader["Y"]}";
```

Comment: Thanks, concatenate string was the one, now i can search for issues like this in the future.

Y is just the representation of the value i get in this case its "test.jpg"

Comment: In case of string.format or interpolation it is not necessary to call .ToString(). Moreover, if value it's null we will get exception

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Where ever i can save a bit of text is great helps me keep track of what I'm doing. I altso get a better understanding of what the tags i use infact do.